# Split commas on string with regular expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I'm beginner at regular expression. I need your advice on it.

I want to split a string by commas which are outside a couple of single quote with regular expression.

Regex pattern: `,(?=([^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)`

String input: `"'2017-10-16 10:44:43.0000000', 'Abc,'', de', '0', None"`

Expected output: `["'2017-10-16 10:44:43.0000000'", " 'Abc,'', de'", " '0'", " None"]` there is an array with 4 elements.

Currently, I'm using split method with regex and It's working well on JAVA.
Now I have to handle it by JavaScript but I have got an unexpected result!

Could you please give me an advice?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: ?? using `.split(',')` should work! what `unexpected result` are you getting?

Comment: @Fallenhero: He doesn't want to split `'Abc,'` in that `input`. That comma is part of the string, it's not a separator.

Comment: no, it's not! As you can see my input, there is some cases one of them has comma inside. `'Abc,'', de'` is one element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex contains a *capturing* group, `([^']*'[^']*')`.

When you use a capturing group in a regex that you pass to [`String#split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) in **Java**, the capturing groups are not added to the resulting split array of strings. In **JavaScript**, [`String#split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) adds all *captured* substrings into the resulting array.

To make the pattern compatible between the two engines, just turn the capturing group with a non-capturing one,

```
,(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)
    ^^^            ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cqqnJD/2).

JS demo:

```js
var rx = /,(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)/;
var s = "'2017-10-16 10:44:43.0000000', 'Abc,'', de', '0', None";
console.log(s.split(rx));
```